# Access return a different value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am working with a database from SharePoint built by someone else.
I am generating a simple pull into a report through Microsoft Access.
I have everything working properly but I have a value that in SharePoint is a list that is for a particular buyer attached to a purchase order. In SharePoint it returns a name value, however in Access it is returning a # Value.
I was wondering if a there was a simple fix that could be made for when the data returned from the SharePoint table returned is = to (specified #) it would return (specified name).

Right now it will return say 137. I would want it to return a buyers name. 
It is a shame conditional formatting doesn't expand into something more than formatting and could actually change If [Field] returns [#value] than return [specified return value] instead.

This is my query from the tables. I am just pulling directly.

```
SELECT
   [115_12 RFQ's].RFQ, [115 Procurement].PO,
   [115 Procurement].[Issued Date],
   [115 Procurement].[C/O],
   [115 Procurement].Status,
   [115 Procurement].Vendor,
   [115_12 RFQ's].[RFQ Title],
   [115 Procurement].[PO Type],
   [115 Procurement].VDR,
   [115 Procurement].[Approval Drawings Required].Value,
   [115 Procurement].[Inspection Required],
   [115 Procurement].[Actual Inspection Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Shipped Date (Vendor)],
   [115 Procurement].[Actual Delivery Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Delivering To?],
   [115 Procurement].[Delivery Required Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Promised Delivery Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Last Vendor Contact Date],
   [115 Procurement].Comments,
   [115_12 RFQ's].Commodity,
   [115_12 RFQ's].Buyers
FROM [115_12 RFQ's]
LEFT JOIN [115 Procurement]
   ON [115_12 RFQ's].ID = [115 Procurement].RFQ;
```

**[115_12 RFQ's].Buyers** is returning numbers those numbers I want to return a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a `Buyers` table in the database that stores the ID (which is what is returned by the query now) and the name of the person associated with the ID. 
For example:

```
[Buyers table]
BuyerID
FullName

137   Tom Jones
138   Fred Smith
```

What you will need to do is find out the name of the table or view that exposes the names of the buyers and modify your query to perform a join to that table/view. From there, you include the name of the buyer from the table instead of or in addition to the Buyer ID.

Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
   [115_12 RFQ's].RFQ, [115 Procurement].PO,
   [115 Procurement].[Issued Date],
   [115 Procurement].[C/O],
   [115 Procurement].Status,
   [115 Procurement].Vendor,
   [115_12 RFQ's].[RFQ Title],
   [115 Procurement].[PO Type],
   [115 Procurement].VDR,
   [115 Procurement].[Approval Drawings Required].Value,
   [115 Procurement].[Inspection Required],
   [115 Procurement].[Actual Inspection Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Shipped Date (Vendor)],
   [115 Procurement].[Actual Delivery Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Delivering To?],
   [115 Procurement].[Delivery Required Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Promised Delivery Date],
   [115 Procurement].[Last Vendor Contact Date],
   [115 Procurement].Comments,
   [115_12 RFQ's].Commodity,
   [115_12 RFQ's].Buyers,
   [Buyers].FullName
FROM [115_12 RFQ's]
LEFT JOIN [115 Procurement]
   ON [115_12 RFQ's].ID = [115 Procurement].RFQ
LEFT JOIN [Buyer] 
ON [115_12 RFQ's].Buyers = [Buyer].BuyerID;
```

Comment: Thank you,
That didn't work because of some retarded problem with my query.
Access is a very fickle beast. I ended up doing something very similar though with a redone query because of what you placed there.
This is what ended up working fabulously.

Comment: SELECT [115_12 RFQ's].Name, 
[115 Procurement].Name, 
[115_12 RFQ's].Commodity, 
[115 Procurement].[Issued Date], 
[115 Procurement].[C/O], 
[115 Procurement].Status, 
[115 Procurement].Vendor, 
[115_12 RFQ's].[RFQ Title], 
[115 Procurement].[PO Type], 
[115 Procurement].VDR, 
[115 Procurement].[Approval Drawings Required], 
[115 Procurement].[Inspection Required], 
[115 Procurement].[Actual Inspection Date], 
[115 Procurement].[Shipped Date (Vendor)], 
[115 Procurement].[Actual Delivery Date], 
[115 Procurement].[Delivering To?],

Comment: [115 Procurement].[Delivery Required Date], 
[115 Procurement].[Promised Delivery Date], 
[115 Procurement].[Last Vendor Contact Date], 
[115 Procurement].Comments, 
[115 Procurement].Commodity, 
[115 Procurement].Buyer, 
UserInfo.ID, 
UserInfo.Name
FROM ([115_12 RFQ's] INNER JOIN [115 Procurement] ON [115_12 RFQ's].[ID] = [115 Procurement].[RFQ]) INNER JOIN UserInfo ON [115_12 RFQ's].Buyer = UserInfo.ID
ORDER BY [115_12 RFQ's].Name;